# How to ask when somebody's holiday will start?

Tags: idiomatic-language, sentence-choice

I want to ask when someone's holiday (vacation) will start. What is the idiomatic question?

Maybe:

1. When are you going on holiday?
2. When does your holiday start?
3. When is your holiday starting?
4. When are you off on holiday?
5. When is the start of your holiday?

Comment: i would be fine with using any of the above, depending on how i wanted to phrase it. 3 and 5 would be less idiomatic, but still acceptable

Comment: Is "when are you on holiday?" idiomatic? It seems to me that some of these questions suggests that you are going somewhere travelling. What if I just want to ask when someone's relaxing time starts whether or not he's going to travel somwhere?

Comment: "when are you on holiday?" is definitely idiomatic, and implies that you want a time range as opposed to a leaving date. The listener would definitely interpret it as being 'time off work' or 'relaxation time' as opposed to traveling.

Answer (score 0):

I would be fine with using any of the above, depending on how I wanted to phrase it. 3 and 5 would be less idiomatic, but still acceptable.

There are plenty more options... "When will your holiday start?" "When do you leave for your holiday?"  and so on.

Comment: How about "when are you on holiday?" ? Some of these questions seem to suggest that you will travel somewhere, don't they? What if I just want to know when someone's period of time to relax starts whether he is or isn't going to travel?